# View local:"UserControl" in ColumnDefinition(2)

Tags: wpf, grid

I want to view UserControl inside ColumnDefinition(2)

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <local:DockPanelTop />
    <local:DockPanelBtm />

    <Grid Margin="5,45,5,25" x:Name="MainGrid" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" MaxWidth="400" MinWidth="0" x:Name="MainMenu" x:FieldModifier="public" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="AliceBlue" />
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFFF7E7E" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="AntiqueWhite" />

        【"View this into ColumnDefinition(2)"<local:TreeView />】

    </Grid>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `<local:TreeView  Grid.Column="2"/>` ?

Comment: @QiXuan: What `UserControl`?

Comment: What do you mean by "view" and "columndefinition"?  As ( i think) ash suggests If you set grid.column ="2" on a user control in that grid then it'll appear in the grid column 2. Which is the third column because zero is the first. That rather sounds like what you're asking. But you've got grid.column 1 in that markup so it looks like you understand how that attached property works.

Comment: @ASh thx bro, that's the answer I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer:

```
<local:TreeView Grid.Column="2"/>
```